# Checkbox doesnt unchecked if it is checked initially in element-plus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

I have checkbox using element-plus:

```html
<el-checkbox
  v-model="slotProps.action.check_control"
  :checked="slotProps.action.check_control"
  size="large"
  class="ml-4"
  :id="slotProps.action.id"
  @change="checkControl(slotProps.action.id, slotProps.action.check_control)"
/>
```

And I make api call with this function: checkControl.

```js
const checkControl = (id, controlled) => {
  loading.value = true
  if (controlled === true) {
    controlled = 1
  } else {
    controlled = 0
  }
  ApiService.postTest('api...', {
    jar_id: id,
    check_control: controlled
  })
    .then((res) => {
      loading.value = false
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      loading.value = false
      console.log(e)
    })
}
```

whats wrong is after the page is rendered, if the checkbox is checked, I click the checkbox, but it checks it again instead of unchecked.

I am not sure if this related with element plus, but here is the documentation about it: https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/checkbox.html#checkbox-attributes

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input
  type="checkbox"
  v-model="foo"
/>
```

is short for

```html
<input
  type="checkbox""
  :checked="foo"
  @change="(e) => { foo = e.target.checked }"
/>
```

See [form input bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms#form-input-bindings).
In the above example, `foo` should be reactive.

Meaning: *"do not use both* `v-model` *and* `:checked` *on same* `<input type="checkbox" />`!"

If removing `:checked` doesn't solve the problem, please provide more detail about how `slotProps.action.check_control` gets populated in the context of your component. Currently, the `js` logic you are showing does not seem related to what you're passing to the `<input />`.

---

To set the `checked` value of the `<input />` programatically, use only `v-model` and set whatever `v-model` points to as `true`, initially.